# H264 on RTP with Facetime

Tags: h.264, rtp, facetime

I'm trying to study Facetime protocol and I see it likes as H264 on RTP. But I think there is something different. Do you know something about its specification?

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely it is actually H264 over SRTP so the stream is encrypted. I would try this page:

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=FaceTime